Scrollwheel click link jump on the page
This is really hard to catch, so no demo video.
Somtimes (1 in 100) when I click on the link to open new tab, page just goes to some random scroll position and no tab gets opened.
This happening on Windows 10.
Here is some catch!

Why my question got a closed state!?!

could it be you are scrollwheel-clicking the link and dragging?  Sometimes I do that and that cancels the request

@Keltari probably, is it possible to somehow disable such beavhiour?

@lisichkaggg yes... hold the mouse in place when you click.  I dont think there is any software workaround.

Have you tried another mouse? Could be the hardware. I've run into a few issues using another workstation in the past when it comes to the mouse wheel on the hardware being so picky it would scroll and not middle click.

I used the same exact mouse for long time and it always has the same exact issue. But only on Windows. No issue on Mac.

When this has happened to me it is due to an aging or bad scroll wheel on a connected mouse where the detents do not match the scroll trigger point. This is especially common for me because I use middle click to "open in a new tab", which then even a tiny movement of the mouse wheel (often the middle mouse button these days) makes the scroll happen.
Replacing the mouse solved the core problem for me, but using CTRL + Click instead of the middle mouse button mitigated the issue until I could replace the mouse.
